D365 Business Central 2024 wave 1 issue connecting to VSCode
I recently installed D365 BC 2024 On Prem tenant for study purposes. I've been having trouble connecting it to VSCode since it gives me the following error message:
[2024-06-02 14:02:44.73] Using reference symbols cache paths: [c:\Users\HP\Documents\AL\GeneratedProject2\.alpackages]
[2024-06-02 14:02:44.83] Targeting server 'http://localhost' and server instance 'BC240'.
[2024-06-02 14:02:44.83] Using Windows authentication.
[2024-06-02 14:02:44.86] Sending request to http://localhost:7049/BC240/dev/metadata
[2024-06-02 14:02:49.16] Error: Could not connect to the server. Please verify that:
1. The server is started.
2. The development endpoint is enabled (DeveloperServicesEnabled server setting).
3. The service name matches the one specified in the URL.
4. The port number matches the one specified in the URL (DeveloperServicesPort server setting).
5. The protocol matches the one specified in the URL (DeveloperServicesSSLEnabled server setting), and that a trusted certificate is used in case of an SSL connection.
[2024-06-02 14:02:49.16] Error: An error occured while processing the request.
Request ID: 906d6e3d-076e-45a0-9563-7eca2e6cb34a
Session ID: e32a782d-9e0f-49c0-ae7d-de0eebb505a6

I've tried changing the Development endpoint using the Admin Powershell but no success.
Could anyone provide insight into anything I might be missing?
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Application just incase I had made a mistake during the installation.
I've tried changing the Development endpoint setting using Windows Powershell but I keep getting the errors on that end as well.
I think it's something quite minute I'm missing.

Could you share the contents of your CustomSettings.config file?

Hi. Sorry for taking so long. I had given up on it and uninstalled to try the 2023 Wave 2 one, only to run into the same issue. Here's a screenshot;
